# Fragments of first-order logic and the functions that preserve them - reference request.

Tags: reference-request, logic

Is there a good resource for learning about different fragments of first-order logic? At this point, I'm mainly just interested in the basic facts, nothing too deep, but preferably presented in a systematic way. The following fragments are especially interesting to me:

- atomic formulae
- literals
- [coherent logic](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+logic#definitions_4) (atomic formulae + $\wedge$ + $\vee$ + $\exists$ + $\top$ + $\bot$) and its dual ($\wedge$ + $\vee$ + $\forall$ + $\top$ + $\bot$)
- as above, but with literals rather than atomic formulae
- full blown [zeroth-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth-order_logic)
- other fragments with good preservation/reflection theorems

Also of interest are the functions that preserve some/all of the aforementioned fragments. I know that at one extreme (all of first-order logic) they're called "elementary embeddings," and at other extreme usually just "homomorphisms," but I'm not sure where to get information about the intermediate fragments and the functions that preserve them.

Thanks.

Comment: Homomorphisms preserve $\land$ and $\lor$ as well. The trouble is with $\to$.

Comment: @ZhenLin, thanks. Does the fragment atomic formulae + $\wedge$ + $\vee$ have a name? This seems like a very sensible fragment to consider, since you basically just stated that there is a nice characterization of the functions which preserve all formulae of this fragment.

Comment: The fragment generated by atomic formulae (including $\top$ and $\bot$), $\land$, $\lor$, and $\exists$ is called [coherent logic](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+logic). (It's easy to check that homomorphisms also preserve $\exists$.) But beware: _literals_ are not preserved, because $\lnot$ is not preserved.

Comment: @ZhenLin, thanks, that seems sensible.

Comment: @ZhenLin, its well known that, in classical logic, homomorphisms preserve a relation iff they reflect its complement. So, what is the fragment reflected by homomorphisms? Clearly it includes negations of atomic formulae, and I'm guessing we can close under $\wedge,$ $\vee$ and $\forall$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.